# The Lie derivative of the Liouville one-form by an infinitesimal symmetry is zero.

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-derivative

Let $(Q,L)$ be a (closed) *Lagrangian system*, that is, a smooth $n$-dimensional manifold $Q$ with an smooth real function $L$ in $Q$. The Lioville one-form $\theta_L$ in $TQ$ is defined in standard coordinates $(q^i,\dot q^i)$ as follows:
$$\theta_L=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q^i} dq^i.$$
Now, let $X$ be an infinitesimal symmetry of $(Q,L)$, i.e., a vector field in $Q$ that satisfies:
$$X^i\frac{\partial L}{\partial q^i}-\dot q^j\frac{\partial X^i}{\partial q^j}\frac {\partial L}{\partial \dot q^i}=0.$$
Following the *Remark* in p.27 of *Quantum Mechanics for Mathematicians by Leon A. Tahkhtajan* it is inmmediate show that:

> **Claim.** The Lie Derivative $\mathcal L_X(\theta_L)=0$.

However, expanding $\mathcal L_X(\theta_L)$ we get:
$$\mathcal L_X(\theta_L)=X^j\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial q^j\partial \dot q^i}dq^i+ \frac{\partial L}{\partial q^i}dX^i.$$
From here, I cannot conclude that the Lie Derivative is zero.

Maybe, I am making a mistake in my calculations.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Lioville $\to$ Liouville